# Confusion between OPEN GL ES and EGL library

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, egl

I was reading android source code in that I am not getting what does  `OPEN GL ES` library do and what does  `EGL library` do.?

Is there any relationship between this two libraries?

I have looked at http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/  but still not getting.

Comment: Crude analogy : `OpenGLES` provides you the brush, the colour paint & the stencil while `EGL` will get you the canvas/paper to paint on.

Comment: wov...if i would ever accept any comment as answer then i will accept ur comment...!!!

Comment: another.anon.coward that is the best explanation ever. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EGL is the interface between OpenGL ES and the underlying native display platform. It is used to create & manage rendering surfaces & graphics contexts.

Answer (score 4):

EGL is used to manage the various display buffers (ie: images you see on the screen) and the OpenGL ES context. These are necessary to *use* OpenGL ES. So you can think of EGL as an initialization layer for OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with programming OpenGL on Windows, MacOSX or Linux - EGL is similar as what [WGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGL_%28software%29) is on Windows, [GLX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgl) is on Linux and what [AGL/CGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_OpenGL) is on MacOSX.

Answer (score 3):

Note that desktop OpenGL has no interaction with EGL, only OpenglES and OpenVG.
Take a look here: [Can anyone explain the way the "Khronos stack" of technologies fits together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8521897)

Answer (score 2):

Open GL is basically an API for creating applications that draw 2D and 3D graphics. EGL allows you to render APIs like OpenGL. You have many pages explaining this, not difficult to find if you google OpenGL and EGL. For example at [khronos](http://www.khronos.org/egl).